# いい versus よい? When do you use which?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between いい and よい？

I notice that usually, いい is most commonly used, but sometimes, I get it wrong and よい is the correct answer. What is the situation to use each and what is the difference?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you supply an example of where よい is the correct answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are quite the same except that よい sounds a bit more formal or contrived depending on the situation but that's all.

What you may already know is that いい only has a 連体形 and a 終止形 which are いい in both cases. For the others bases you have to use よい.

連用形　→　よく・よかっ; ex: よくない・よかった
未然形　→　よかろう

Some expressions explicitly call for よい but it is rare and most of the time rather archaic usage. (ex: 聞くが良い - You should listen)

Comment: You do sometimes find 聞くがいい and the like, though (I know in one work of fiction, a character uses this kind of command all the time, such as 覚悟するがいい and 任せるがいい).

Answer (score 12):

(Please see this as an appendix to the first poster's answer.)

1. As the other post says, when they can be used interchangeably, いい sounds more informal/colloquial and よい sounds more formal/literary.

---

2. いい doesn't have 未然形, 連用形, and 仮定形:

> 未然: よかろ(-う)
>   連用: よかっ(-た)・よく
>   終止: よい・いい
>   連体: よい・いい
>   仮定: よけれ(-ば)
>   命令: ---

You'd also find archaic/fossilized よかれ-/よから-/よき-/よし in set phrases like:

> [良]{よ}かれ[悪]{あ}しかれ (for better or worse)
>   よかれと思って (out of good intentions)  　
>   よからぬ (≒ よくない、悪い) e.g. よからぬこと　よからぬ噂
>   よき友 (≒ いい友達)
>   古き良き時代 (good old days)
>   よし！/ よっしゃあ！
>   (～で)よしとする (settle for ~~)

*よかれ, よから and よき are 命令形, 未然形 and 連体形 of archaic adjective よし, respectively.

---

3. You use よい for some (set) phrases:

> ほどよい (≒ちょうどいい; moderate; proper)
>   よりよい (better)
>   よさ (noun form)
>   よさそう (+ 様態の助動詞「そう」; sounds good)
>   住みよい (≒ 住み易い; liveable)

And いい for several (set) phrases:

> いいね！
>   かっこいい
>   いい男 (≒ イケメン)
>   いい女 (≒ 美人)
>   「もういいかい？」--「もういいよ」(when playing hide and seek)
>   いい人ができた (got a boyfriend/girlfriend)
>   いい奴
>   いい仲 (romantic relationship)
>   (いい is often used for set phrases with negative nuance or sarcasm:)
>   いい[気味]{きみ}だ
>   いい[様]{ざま}だ
>   いい気になる (carried away)
>   いい加減な (irresponsible, inaccurate, etc.)
>   いい歳をして
>   いい顔をする
>   いい恥さらしだ
>   いい迷惑だ