# "Hiatus avoidance" in Japanese?

Tags: pronunciation, readings, phonology

Is the reading

腕【うで】の良【よ】い医者【いしゃ】

or

腕【うで】の良【い】い医者【いしゃ】?

どんなに腕【うで】の良【よ】い医者【いしゃ】に早【はや】くかかったとしても間【ま】に合【あ】わない

*No matter how fast you go to a good doctor, you won't make it.*

https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/291173

In British English, there is a phenomenon called "hiatus avoidance" (http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/classical-elision.html) and I was wondering whether Japanese has a similar phenomenon.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28073/45489

Comment: The links seems to talk only about hiatus avoidance in Latin and nothing about British English. Do you have any example in British English?

Comment: In brief, my impression is that modern Japanese generally does not elide morae, simply because that often produces different words with different meanings.  The language is rife with examples of words ending in vowels stacked right next to words beginning with the same vowel even.  This is sometimes used for humorous effect, such as: 「鳳凰【ほうおう】を追【お】おう」 ("let's chase the phoenix").  Omit any of the stacked "o"s here, and you alter the meaning.  Is this the kind of thing you're asking about?

Comment: @aguijonazo: Any example of a British intrusive /r/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R#Intrusive_R

Comment: Some people say ばわい and まわい meaning 場合 and 間合い, respectively.